# sql to populate newly created link table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would be really grateful if somebody could help me out with this..

I actually have 2 tables in my database: books and authorlist.

The `book` table contains a field '`book_aut`' which contains the foreign key of the `authorlist` table.

The `authorlist` table has only 2 fields, the primary key and the 'authors' column which contains a list of names.

I have to modify the table structure so that `books` table is linked to an `authors` table via a link table called '`lnk_book_author`'

So my first task is to create a new table called 'authors' which contains 3 fields - primary id, name, surname, which i already did.

Next, i created the link table called '`lnk_book_author`' and this one contains 3 fields, the primary id, book_fk, author_fk. The book_fk and author_fk refer to the id of the book and author respectively.

My problem is that i have more than 6000 entries in the books table and i would like to know how to populate the link table with the book id and the author id.

Is there a way of doing that using sql instead of manually populating the lnk_book_author table.

Hope i was clear enough..

Thanks a lot for any suggestion provided.

Comment: Your old world has `a list of names` in the [authors] column of [authorlist].  Is this a single string, comma delimitered list?  And are the names in such a list *Identical* to the [name] column of the [authors] table?

Comment: the list of names is a comma delimited list, yes they are identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm infering the IDs already in your new [authors] table mean nothing with regards to the old tables.  If that's the case you need to relate the records by the Name.  And there I need to assume that the names are entered Identically.  If they're not, it may not be possible to do.  We'd need to know a lot more specifics to be sure...

```
INSERT INTO
  lnk_book_author
SELECT
  Books.PrimaryKeyFieldName,
  Authors.PrimaryKeyFieldName
FROM
  Books
INNER JOIN
  AuthorList
    ON Books.BookAut = AuthorList.PrimaryKeyFieldName
INNER JOIN
  Authors
    ON CONCAT(',', AuthorList.Authors, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', Authors.Name, ',%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```
INSERT INTO lnk_book_author(book_fk,author_fk)
SELECT b.book_id,a.author_id
FROM books b INNER JOIN authorlist a
ON b.book_aut=a.author_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joss, i will try it but the thing is that it's a many to many relationship between books table and authors table..before we used to have a one to one relationship between books and authorlist coz authorlist contains a list of all author names

Comment: Yes I understood. But you need to populate your n-n table with your 1-n existing data once.

Comment: I think (and it's a bit of interefence) that part of the problem is [AuthorList] contains multiple authors per row in one field, and [Authors] contains only one author per row.  Thus also meaning the IDs for [Authors] bear no resemblence to the IDs for [AuthorList]?

Comment: Yes!!That's true, the IDs for [Authors] bear no resemblence to the IDs for [AuthorList]

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work:

```
INSERT INTO lnk_book_author (book_fk, author_fk)
VALUES ((SELECT Id FROM books), (SELECT Id FROM authors))
```

And by the way there's no point having an Id column in the lnk_book_authors table, you may as well just make the foreign keys a composite primary key.

**UPDATE**

Sorry I realise that would only work with one record, try the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO lnk_book_author (book_fk, author_fk)
SELECT books.Id, authors.Id
FROM books, authors
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i seem to be getting the following error message: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: You need to add in the relationship between the two tables.  The EDIT gives every author against every book...

Comment: @Dems I am assuming she has already created the table added the FK relationships via the editor prior to running the script